# Show that $\{\cos(nx)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a complete system in $L_2[0, \pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, complete-spaces

I need to show that $\{\cos(nx)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a complete system in $L_2[0, \pi]$.

My idea was to declare $g(x):=\begin{cases} f(x) &\text{if } x\in [0,\pi]  \\{}\\ f(-x) &\text{ if } x\in [-\pi,0]\end{cases}$.

Since $g \in L_2[-\pi, \pi]$ and $\{1, \cos(nx), \sin(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a complete system,

then for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there is $ h \in\operatorname{span}(\{1, \cos(nx), \sin(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty})$ such that $\|g(x) - h(x)\|_2 < \epsilon$.

Now, $h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n\cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n\sin(nx)$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

From the above I get $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin(nx)$
, and since $g(x) = g(-x)$ it follows that $0 = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin(nx)$.

Here is where I got stuck. I want to say $b_n = 0$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin(nx) = 0$ doesn't guarantee that (for example $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$).

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: If $\sum b_n \sin(nx) \equiv 0$ then multiply by $\sin(Nx)$ and integrate. All terms except the $b_N$ term will vanish and you are left with $b_N = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I see that works. Thanks!